# Can I use http command to place order in GDAX?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I see that I can read the price of bitcoin using

'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/ticker'

Can I place and cancel the order via a http command?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

https://docs.gdax.com/

There are examples there in various languages.